# Possible Error In the Feeds Header

Tags: discussion, bug, android-app, android-app-feed, android

I am on **Android**

While browsing the Stacks Exchange(app is the latest version) Data Science using my smartphone,

**Feeds section**,

Just switch the **Questions** to **Users** 
And then 
Revert back using the **back** key of the phone,

The feed changes to again display the recent Questions but the header still shows that it's Pointing to **Users** Section..

Moreover if your in the second state and select a Question to read or answer,
And then again press the back button,
You are directed to the Users Tab but I 
**Should have got directed to the Questions tab**

Sorry for my English if it's making it look Complex...

Here's the screen shots associated with the same..
[image: Feed showing Users]

[image: Feed showing Questions but still shows Users in the header]